# XSLT: Applying Templates to an element outside the current scope

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

```
<root>
   <warningsAndCautions>
     <warning id="w1">
        <warningAndCautionPara>This is Warning 1, to fix refer to: 
            <dmref><dmcode assyCode="0001" disassyCode"00" disassyCodeVariant="X"
                      infoCode="001" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="A"
                      modelIdentCode="AA" subSubSystemCode="9" subSystemCode="0"
                      systemCode="00" systemDiffCode="A"/>
            .
        </warningAndCautionPara>
     </warning>
     <warning id="w2">
        <warningAndCautionPara>This is Warning 1, to fix refer to: 
           <dmref><dmcode assyCode="1111" disassyCode"11" disassyCodeVariant="X"
                      infoCode="111" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="A"
                      modelIdentCode="AA" subSubSystemCode="9" subSystemCode="0"
                      systemCode="11" systemDiffCode="A"/>
        .
        </warningAndCautionPara>
     </warning>
   </warningsAndCautions>

   <content>
     <step warningRef="W1">
        <para>Step 1</para>
        <para>Description 1</para>
     </step>
     <step>
        <para>Step 2</para>
        <para>Description 2</para>
     </step>
   </content>
</root>
```

Sample of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="step">
   <xsl:variable name="warnRef">
      <xsl:value-of select="./@warningRef"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <!-- If there is a warningRef attribute on the step, process the associated <warning> element -->
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($warnRef='')">
      <!-- Need to somehow call the template to process the <warning> element with the id of w1 -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The output I am trying to get is something like this:

```
**WARNING:**  This is Warning 1, to fix refer to: 0001-00-X-001-A-A-AA-9-0-00-A .
Step 1
Description 1

Step 2
Description 2
```

I am trying figure out how to write XSLT to produce the WARNING statement above.   When I am processing the `<step>` template I need to check to see if there is a `warningRef` attribute.  If there is I need to process the `<warning>` element that has the id of the `warningRef`.  I just cannot figure out how to apply the template for `<warningAndCautionPara>` when I am processing the  element.  Since it is not a child element of `<step>` apply-template does not work.  As you can see it is mixed content so I need to make sure the `<dmRef>` template is processed also.

Comment: Your XML input example is not well-formed!!

Answer (score 2):

XSLT has a built-in [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) mechanism for handling cross-references. To use it, start by defining a key at the top-level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="warning" match="warning" use="@id" />
```

Then use this key to apply templates to the referenced warning from within the current step, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="step">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('warning', @warningRef)"/>
    <!-- instructions for processing the step -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="warning">
    <!-- instructions for processing the warning -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**:
XML is case-sensitive: a `warningRef="W1"` will **not** match `<warning id="w1">`.

Comment: Yes thank you.  I realized that.  Typo on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

The call you need is something like :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//warning[@id=$warnRef]" />
```

Note: in your above example, it may not work properly, because the reference is written 'W1' and the id is 'w1' - beware of matching case.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.  This worked for me.  The other was a typo on my behalf.  Thanks again.